# SymFullRankQ - a function that calculates the conditions for a matrix to be full rank

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I found in [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.835.5970&rep=rep1&type=pdf) article references to a function that manages to do this:

> is used to find the conditions for the symbolic matrix
>   E to have full rank

This is actually very interesting and useful. Does anyone have the definition of this function?  Or an idea of how it may have been implemented?

Comment: Why don't you ask the authors of the paper directly over [researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/48353457_Mathematica_implementation_of_output-feedback_pole_assignment_for_uncertain_systems_via_symbolic_algebra)?

Comment: I think I might just do that. If I find anything I'll add an answer.

Comment: Note that the authors of the paper you linked seem to cite a [dissertation](https://www.librarysearch.manchester.ac.uk/discovery/fulldisplay?docid=alma9920880654401631&context=L&vid=44MAN_INST:MU_NUI&lang=en&search_scope=MyInst_and_CI&adaptor=Local%20Search%20Engine&tab=Everything&query=creator,contains,soylemez,AND&sortby=rank&mode=advanced&offset=0) by [M. T. Söylemez](http://soylemez.com/en/) at the University of Manchester as the source of that function. This may be hard to track down, and I'd certainly suggest getting in touch with some of the authors.